# CSS div float:left problem, columns have different height

Tags: html, css

```css
div.post {
  min-height: 40px;
}

div.a {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div.b {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div.c {
  width: 35%;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Float Left</title>

<div class="post container">
  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>
</div>
```

I need to make 3 column with same height. How can I do this?

Comment: Which are the columns? Is `a` a single column? This could be a good case for using a css `grid`

Comment: If you want to have all the same height you should really use `display: flex` instead of floats. Or maybe `display: grid` suits your needs even better.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use floats for this, use flexbox instead. You can also use `display: grid;` but for your simple layout flexbox should do the job just fine.

```css
div.post {
  min-height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div.a {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div.b {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

div.c {
  flex: 0 0 35%;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Float Left</title>

<div class="post container">
  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a perfect example to use CSS Grid, you can read about it here:

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

You could have something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 35% 35%;
}

.a {
 grid-column-start: 1;
 grid-column-end: 2;
 background-color: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.b {
 grid-column-start: 2;
 grid-column-end: 3;
 background-color: blue;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.c {
 grid-column-start: 3;
 grid-column-end: 4;
   background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Float Left</title>

<div class="post container">
  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>

  <div class="a">Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw
    at Manchester United</div>
  <div class="b">at 12:00 am</div>
  <div class="c">by gm</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use flex or grid for the layouts instead of float left and right. 
See the below working demo.

```css
div.post {
  min-height: 40px;
}

p.a {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p.b {
  width: 35%;
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

p.c {
  width: 35%;
  background-color: yellow;
  min-height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Float Left</title>

<div class="post container">

  <div class="d-flex">
    <p class="a">
      Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at
      Manchester United
    </p>
    <p class="b">at 12:00 am</p>
    <p class="c">by gm</p>
  </div>

  <div class="d-flex">
    <p class="a">
      Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at
      Manchester United
    </p>
    <p class="b">at 12:00 am</p>
    <p class="c">by gm</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <p class="a">
      Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at
      Manchester United
    </p>
    <p class="b">at 12:00 am</p>
    <p class="c">by gm</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <p class="a">
      Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at
      Manchester United
    </p>
    <p class="b">at 12:00 am</p>
    <p class="c">by gm</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <p class="a">
      Premier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at Manchester UnitedPremier League: Liverpool drop points for the 1st time after 1-1 draw at
      Manchester United
    </p>
    <p class="b">at 12:00 am</p>
    <p class="c">by gm</p>
  </div>
</div>
```